# Parameter '@home' specified but none of the passed arguments...Error message

Tags: petapoco

I am having an sql statement as follows:

```
SELECT [User].[ID], 
    [User].[Name],
    [User].[Email] 
FROM [User] 
WHERE Email = 'user@home.com''
```

and it's firing an error as follows from petaPOCO:

> Parameter '@home' specified but none of the passed arguments have a
>   property with this name (in 'SELECT [User].[ID], [User].[Name],
>   [User].[Email] FROM [User] WHERE Email = 'user@home.com'')

what does the error message implies? What is wrong with the sql statement? Does petaPOCO not accept '@' in an sql statement?I need to do a search by email address.

Comment: The real question is why you aren't using parameters?

Comment: PetaPoco does support named parameters. That's why this error exists.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to put two @ symbols to escape the character since it is used to prefix parameters normally.

So your value would need to be `'user@@home.com`'.